# Docker install forces QWERTY keyboard configuration?

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, keyboard, docker

I've installed Docker on a fresh empty copy of Ubuntu 14.04 mounted under VirtualBox.

```
sudo apt-get -y install docker.io
```

However, when I log out and in again, the AZERTY keyboard is switched to QWERTY. I can switch it back to normal, but the QWERTY keeps coming up after logout...

```
setxkbmap fr
```

Any clue why this behaviour?

My host computer runs Linux LMDE, and I mounted Ubuntu 14.04 in VirtualBox 5.0.2, with the English language and the French AZERTY keyboard.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

The quick and easy way:

```
echo "setxkbmap fr" >> /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc
```

If that does not work and you have tried to reboot your virtual machine after running the command, then check if docker created a user-specific xinit file located at `~/.xinitrc` and add the keyboard map command at the *end* of that file too.

If you want to find out how it works have a look at the ArchWiki [Xinit](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xinit) page, the [Keyboard configuration in Xorg](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Keyboard_configuration_in_Xorg) page might also be useful.

Disclaimer: I have not tested this.